# What's a good way to create an Event Calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I want to create an Event Calendar for my iPhone App. In a first instance the Event Calendar is supposed to list the Events and have a Details View with additional info. It is also supposed to contain an action to trasfer a specific event to the iPhone Calendar.

First thoughts go towards using a UITableView where I make the event dates as sections. Since the Calendar is supposed to span many month I am unsure whether this really is the best way to go about it.

Any suggestions? Do you probably know some sample code that I might use ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Kal](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal) control.  It's basically a pixel-for-pixel duplicate of the calendar control in the Calendar app.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Dave, looks really good. Will give it a shot :)